# How to implement something like Terracota?

Tags: jvm, terracotta

How Terracotta knows that object is changed inside one JVM to propagate this change to another JVM? I.e. how can I code similar behavior?

I want to be able to watch changes in instances of some classes, without changing them at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses [instrumentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html). It's explained (in high level) in the [terracotta wiki](http://www.terracotta.org/confluence/display/docs/Concept+and+Architecture+Guide#ConceptandArchitectureGuide-BytecodeInstrumentation)

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't a observer pattern help. If you implement your class as observable and have an oberver , the observer will be notified when ever the observable class goes through some change.